# A collapsing table row when no data is found in the 3 columns (Active Campaign)

Tags: javascript, html, activecampaign

OK so i am using Active campign to run my marketing for my website and i am designing my emails using custom HTML.

What i want is simply when no data is recieved fir the table row in any of my 3 columns then to not show that row.

When i build this in visual studio code it works perfectly when i send to live server as shown.

[Table working in live server no first row collapsed as no data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pu39r.png)

Now when i paste this same HTML code into active campaign it shows like this

[Table not collapsing row one as you can see it has the double thick line at top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XRHX.png)

Whats strange that when i see the preview in active campaign i see the SCRIPT code as regular text at the top see here. So the code is not running.

[See at top you can see the text of the script so its not running as script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1xaZ.png)

Here is my code if anyone can help id appriecate it

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
   <meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/line-awesome/1.3.0/line-awesome/css/line-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha512-vebUliqxrVkBy3gucMhClmyQP9On/HAWQdKDXRaAlb/FKuTbxkjPKUyqVOxAcGwFDka79eTF+YXwfke1h3/wfg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <title>HTML Email Signature</title>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function()
      {
         $("#mealplantable tr td").each(function()
         {
            var emptyrows=$.trim($(this).text());
            if(emptyrows.length==0)
            {
               $(this).parent().hide();
            }
         });
      });

   </script>

    <style type="text/css">

      table.mealplantable th {
         text-align: center;
         border-collapse: collapse;
         border: 1px solid #000;
         font-family: 'Roboto', serif, sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica;
         padding: 0;
         font-weight: 700;
         font-size: 15px;
      }

      table.mealplantable tr {
         font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
         padding: 0;
         font-weight: 700;
         font-size: 15px;
      }

      table.mealplantable td {
         text-align: center;
         border-collapse: collapse;
         border: 1px solid #000;
         font-family: 'Roboto', serif, sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica;
         padding: 0;
         font-weight: 400;
         font-size: 15px;
      }

      .mealplantable {
         border: 1px solid #000;
         padding-top: 0;
         padding-right: 0;
         padding-left: 0;
         padding-bottom: 0;
         margin: 0 auto;
         width: 99%;
         max-width: 600px;
         border-spacing: 0;
         font-family:'Roboto', serif, sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica;
         color: #000;
         margin-top: 10px;
         margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      table {
            border-spacing: 0;
        }
        td {
            padding: 0;
        }
        img {
            border: 0;
            border-width:0;
        }
        a {
            color: #000000;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

    </style>

    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <style type="text/css">
            table {border-collapse: collapse !important;}
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
    
</head>

<body style="Margin:0;padding-top:0;padding-right:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0;min-width:100%;background-color:#dde0e1;">

         <table align="center" width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0;" role="presentation" >
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <!-- If its a normal email you can just start your paragraphs right here anything else you need to build more tables inside this -->
                  <table class="mealplantable" role="presentation" id ="mealplantable">
                     <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th>Food</th>
                        <th>Cooked Weight</th>
                        <th>Raw Weight</th>
                        </tr>
                     </thead>
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td></td>
                           <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color: #ebd06a;">
                           <td>%M12_FOOD%</td>
                           <td>%M12_WEIGHT%</td>
                           <td>%M12_RAW%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>%M13_FOOD%</td>
                           <td>%M13_WEIGHT%</td>
                           <td>%M13_RAW%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color: #ebd06a;">
                           <td>%M14_FOOD%</td>
                           <td>%M14_WEIGHT%</td>
                           <td>%M15_RAW%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>%M15_FOOD%</td>
                           <td>%M15_WEIGHT%</td>
                           <td>%M15_RAW%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color: #ebd06a;">
                           <td>%M16_FOOD%</td>
                           <td>%M16_WEIGHT%</td>
                           <td>%M16_RAW%</td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>

         <!-- End second table-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).